# document Path is showing nil for .doc file but working for .txt objective c cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, filepath

I am using below code

// it is showing nil for `path`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filetext.doc" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

// it is showing working

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filetext.txt" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Please help what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a), the method returns `nil` if the file cannot be found. The conclusion, therefore, is that the file is missing. Check your project's Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources to ensure that the file is actually present because in all likelihood it is not.

Comment: file included into the project. Both files are on same place .txt and .doc

Comment: So when you go to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Applications/7.x/.../your.app`, the file is actually there?

Comment: It was not there... I put that and it is working.

But it is not showing content in WebView in cocoa mac os x app.

Comment: I am creating a msoffice document viewer for mac os x app. May you help me how can do that?

Comment: That's probably an unrelated problem. And it's also a separate question so you should ask a new question about that if you can't get it working by yourself within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I already asked a question and it is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357237/edit-open-doc-pdf-xls-file-in-objective-c-for-mac-os-x-app